# How to create only one li element per call to d3.append?

Tags: jquery, d3.js, tabs, html-lists

I'm passing in the name of a checkbox option in JQuery d3 in order to render a new tab `li` element with the same name.

But what I tried passing in the option name eg, "option1" creates a new tab for each letter in the string using the `.data(val)` option.

So in my example below `val = "option1"` and I create the tab like this:

```
d3.select("ul#chartTabs")
                .selectAll("li")
                .data(val)
                .enter()
                .append('li')
                .insert("a", ":first-child")
                .attr("data-toggle", "tab")
                .attr("id", function(val, i){ var result = val + i; return result; })
                .text(function(d){ return d; })
```

**Question:**

How can I create only one tab per call to d3.append?

This is the current output when passing in the val `"option1"`. Which is *not* as expected as it creates a new tab for each letter. Instead of a single button with value option1.

[image]

Comment: ok that works, but I did notice that a second call to this code removes the previous button "option1" with the new button "option2". What I'm looking for is to add the new button option2 alongside option1 button. Any ideas there?

Comment: You are missing the point of the data-binding.  If you want multiple `li`, there shouldn't be multiple calls.  Just one call with data like `.data(['option1','option2'])`.

Comment: In this use case a user has a list of chart options, the user selects an option which creates a new button and chart. Selecting a subsequent option appends another button and chart. This allows a user to tab between rendered charts. Instead of having to draw all in one go.

Comment: Or are you suggesting to render all the buttons on selection of one chart option. And hide the extra tabs created until an option is selected?

Comment: No, it sounds like for your use case you just want to skip the binding and append them one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d3 is coercing your string to an array, you could just use `.data([val])`, or skip the data-binding all together since you aren't really using it:

```
d3.select("ul#chartTabs")
  .append('li')
  .insert("a", ":first-child")
  .attr("data-toggle", "tab")
  .attr("id", val + "0")
  .text(val);
```

If you really want multiple `li`, don't call this code iterative-ly, you then want the data-binding.

```
d3.select("ul#chartTabs")
  .selectAll("li")
  .data(["option1", "option2", "option3"])
  ...
```